# How to move the position of a calculated circle?

Tags: c++, math, opengl

**The situation**
I currently have a working method that correctly calculates the circumference. each position within the circumference, is stored within an array of structs. My camera position moves along the circle depending on the position within the array. Each element of the array holds the x,y and z values of the position within 3d space.

**The problem:**
The position of the circle seems to be located at x:0,y:0,z:0 with a radius of 3 however I need it to be at another location within 3d space (x:10,y:35,z:20) with a radius of 3.

My struct:

```
typedef struct 
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    } circle;
circle loop[600] = {0};
```

My method that calculates the circle:

```
void calcCircle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 599 ; i++)
            {
                loop[i].x = radius * sin(i/100.0);
                loop[i].y = 10;
                loop[i].z = radius * cos(i/100.0);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add an offset to your calculations, eg to center at `10,35,20`...

```
const double PI = 3.1415926535;
void calcCircle()
{
    for (double i = 0; i < 2*PI ; i+=PI*2/600)
            {
                loop[i].x = 10 + radius * sin(i/2*PI);
                loop[i].y = 35;
                loop[i].z = 20 + radius * cos(i/2*PI);
            }

}
```

Note that your example isn't centered at `0,0,0` but at `0,10,0` - if you still want the camera to be 10 above, add an additional 10 to your `y` value.

Also, it's more common to provide the center to orbit and some offsets to the camera rather than pre-calculating *n* points. That way, the camera can move smoothly instead of between fixed points. As it stands, the speed of orbit is likely tied to framerate which can vary between devices.

Finally, I've changed the scaling of your `sin`/`cos` so that it will describe one complete orbit in 600 steps.

Comment: My pleasure. Welcome to SO - Hope we see you around in future